# Find User on Basis of Lat long

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, query-performance

I want to find users which are under 5 miles location and having the same tag that I have.

**The structure of my data:**

```
UserTable

--------------------------------------
 userid | name | lat | long | address
--------------------------------------
  101   |  xyz |  92 |  72  | NY
  201   |  HYS |  48 |  56  | JAMAICA
  301   |  LMN |  92 |  75  | Brazil


TagTable

---------------------
 id | userid | tagid
---------------------
  1 |   101  |   5
  2 |   201  |   7
  3 |   301  |   5
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT vb.userid,
       vb.address,
       ( 6371 * ACOS(   COS( RADIANS( 28.684342 ) )
                          * COS( RADIANS( vb.lat ) ) 
                          * COS( RADIANS( vb.long) - RADIANS( 77.137941 ) )
                      + SIN( RADIANS( 28.684342 ) )
                          * SIN( RADIANS( vb.lat) )
                    )
       ) AS distance
  FROM UserTable vb, TagTable vk
 WHERE vk.userid = vb.userid
   AND vk.tagid = '5'
 GROUP BY vk.userid
HAVING distance < 10
 ORDER BY distance;
```

The above query is taking lot of time, kindly help me to find the fastest query for this scenario.

Comment: use sql indexing to process query faster..

Comment: write now it taking 11.00 sec after indexing it taking 10.00 sec there is not marginal diffrence

Comment: before indexing it took 11.000 second after applying indexing on tagid and userid , its taking 10.000 seconds. i want this query to execute in less than 1-2 sec

Comment: did you applied it on both table..

Comment: in UserTable userid is the primary field , and have applied indexing on  lat  long

Comment: Yo should decide what database you are using:  MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: apply indexing on tagid and userid of tagtable...n please change your long field name it is a datatype too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indexing doesn't make a big difference I might try and take some of the heavy computational steps out, and see how that improves efficiency:

Idea 1: remove the `ORDER BY` clause, and instead sort in PHP.

Idea 2: then also remove the `HAVING` clause, and instead filter in PHP as you loop through the results.

Idea 3: If a `userid` can only appear once for a particular `tagid` in `TagTable`, remove the whole `GROUP BY` clause, and add the distance test into the `WHERE` clause.

I'm not sure if passing off some of the processing to PHP would help efficiency, by it's worth testing at least.

Comment: Ideas 1 and 2 won't help any.  All the heavy lifting happened before that.

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle's [Spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b28004/xe_locator.htm#CIHFBGJG) data

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db050/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable (
  userid   NUMBER(8,0),
  name     VARCHAR2(255),
  location SDO_GEOMETRY,
  address  VARCHAR2(255)
);

INSERT INTO UserTable
          SELECT 101, 'xyz', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(92,72,NULL), NULL, NULL), 'NY' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 201, 'HYS', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(48,56,NULL), NULL, NULL), 'JAMACA' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 301, 'LMN', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(92,75,NULL), NULL, NULL), 'Brazil' FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (
  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO, SRID
) VALUES (
  'USERTABLE',
  'LOCATION', 
  SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LONG', -180.0, 180.0, 0.5), 
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LAT', -90.0, 90.0, 0.5)
  ), 
  8307
);

CREATE INDEX UserTable_SIDX ON UserTable( location ) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;

CREATE TABLE TagTable (id, userid, tagid ) AS
          SELECT 1, 101, 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 201, 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 301, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT u.userid
FROM   UserTable u
       INNER JOIN
       TagTable t
       ON u.UserID = t.UserID
WHERE  sdo_within_distance (
         u.location,
         SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(92,72,NULL), NULL, NULL),
         'distance=5 unit=MILE'
       ) = 'TRUE'
AND    t.tagid = 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db050/2/0)**:

```
| USERID |
|--------|
|    101 |
```

Comment: hey i used geolatlong librbary for and coverted my lat long into a single coloum, and now its giving a respinse time of 1.0 seconds , which will be faster this code or the geolatlong?

Comment: Never tries geolatlong library so it would be best if you profile both (including ensuring you have appropriate indexes) then you can work out which is better for your data. But I can't answer which is quicker as there are lots of variables (hardware, partitioning, indexes, volume of data, etc) that will affect any answer.

Comment: thank you MT0, Ill let you know when i implement the same