# Creating a spatial index on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, geospatial, spatial-index

I have a table 'floating_options', and I want to create a spatial index on a column 'area_geo' (which is a sdo_geometry column, with two rows of data that appear as expected when I select * from floating_options).

I have used the following code but I am receiving the error below. I would be very grateful for any help! Thanks!

```
CREATE INDEX area_idx ON floating_options(area_geo)
   INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;


Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-13203: failed to read USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view
ORA-13203: failed to read USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. In the future, please use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output/errMsgs/etc. Good Luck

Comment: I have [a previous example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33258347/1509264) - I'm not going to re-post it as @micklesh has covered the bits that you're missing in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before indexing the table you should have it 'spatially enabled'.
Try to check if it is shown in spatial metadata:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('floating_options')
      AND COLUMN_NAME = UPPER('area_geo');
```

If there are no results - then a couple of options are available.
One dirty way - insert data directly

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA
VALUES (UPPER('floating_options'),UPPER('area_geo'),
        mdsys.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
             mdsys.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Easting', <lowest_x>, <highest_x>, <x_tolerance>),
             mdsys.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Northing', <lowest_y>, <highest_y>, <y_tolerance>)
        ), <SRID>);
```

Please change the < **placeholders** > accordingly

Please take a look also at https://community.oracle.com/thread/836452?tstart=0 or 
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/oracle_spatial/metadata

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. This has successfully inserted a row into the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA table, which I can see when I query it as you advise above.

However when I do this on the table I mention above and the same on another table with point coordinates (using the INSERT INTO statement you have described above) and then use a SDO_CONTAINS query, I still get:
{ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index}, potentially suggesting that it hasn't successfully created an index.

Comment: Well, this insert does not create any index.  You should now create spatial index as you have already tried: CREATE INDEX area_idx ON floating_options(area_geo) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;

Answer (score 4):

The following should also be considered: Oracle has case-sensitive names [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563090/oracle-what-exactly-do-quotation-marks-around-the-table-name-do).

The next problem with the "intelligent" guys of Oracle is, that their USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA table does not support lower-case names (at least in 11g).

So with for a table definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE "cola_markets" (
  "mkt_id" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" VARCHAR2(32),
  "shape" SDO_GEOMETRY);
```

you cannot create a spatial index.

When inserting the metadata

```
INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA 
  VALUES (
  'cola_markets',
  'shape',
  SDO_DIM_ARRAY(   -- 20X20 grid
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 20, 0.005),
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 20, 0.005)
     ),
  NULL   -- SRID
);
```

the names are converted to upper-case.

If you then create the index

```
CREATE INDEX cola_spatial_idx
   ON "cola_markets"("shape")
   INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

You will get the error mentioned above

```
ORA-13203: failed to read USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA view
```

because it cannot find the lower-case names in the metadata table.

Conclusion:

- use only upper-case names (or no double quotes)
- Orcale guys are blockheads

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata 
VALUES ('target_table', 'SHAPE', sdo_dim_array(sdo_dim_element('x',-180,180,.005),sdo_dim_element('y',-90,90,.005)), 4326);

create index new_index_table on target_table(SHAPE) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index;
```

It should work.